# Is $|\sin(x+h)-\sin x-h\cos x|<h^2/2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

This is a problem taken from the book by Boris Demidovich *Problems in Mathematical Analysis*. I quote the text *verbatim*:

> Show that $\sin{(x+h)}$ differs from $$\sin{x}+h\cos{x}$$ by not more than $1/2\cdot h^2$

This, I suppose, amounts to showing that $$|\sin(x+h)-\sin x-h\cos x|<\frac{h^2}2.$$ However, using Wolfram Alpha, I noticed that the inequality doesn't hold for certain values of $x$ and $h$. Is it a mistake of mine or is the statement of the problem incorrect?

Comment: Could you quote some of the "certain values"?

Comment: For $h=3$, Wolfram says that the inequality holds only for $x=2\pi\cdot n +\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Hmm, $h^2/2$ appears in the taylor expansion of cos(h).  My advice is to expand the trig functions in their taylor series. Maybe get some nice cancellation?

Comment: Sorry though, I made a mess with the variables. I just edited the question.

Comment: For $h =0$, the inequality does not hold.

Comment: @Nicol: For $x=0, h=3$ I get $|\sin(x+h)-\sin x-h\cos x|\approx 2.85$ which is easily less than $3^2/2$.

Comment: The $<$ needs to be $\le $

Comment: @HenningMakholm but shouldn't that hold for *all* x?

Comment: @Nicol: You claimed that it holds only for odd multiples of $\pi$. I'm giving you at least one $x$ that works for $h=3$ but is _not_ an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Guess I've messed with Wolfram Alpha, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand $f(h) = \sin(x+h)$ in its polynomial of order $2$ at $h=0$ to get

$$\sin(x+h) = \sin x+ h \cos(x) +f''(\xi) h^2/2$$

Because $|f''|\leqslant 1$, you obtain the required bound.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin(x+h)-\sin x-h\cos x=\int_0^h\left(\cos(x+t)-\cos(x)\right)\,dt$$

$$=\int_0^h\int_0^t\left(-\sin(x+u)\,du\right)\,dt$$

So, since $\vert \sin \vert \le 1$ and $\vert\int f(x)\,dx\vert\le\vert\int \vert f(x)\vert\,dx\vert$:

$$\vert\sin(x+h)-\sin x-h\cos x\vert\le\left\vert\int_0^{h}\int_0^t 1\,du\,dt\right\vert\le\left\vert\int_0^{h}t\,dt\right\vert=\frac{1}{2}h^2$$

as required.